# Redirect all plot output to specific file

Tags: r, plot, output-redirect

**I want to automatically redirect *all* plotting to a file** (reason: see below). Is there a non-hacky way of accomplishing that?

Lacking that, I’m actually not afraid of overriding the built-in functions, I’m *that* desperate. The easiest way I can think of is to hook into the fundamental plot-window creation function and calling `pdf(…)` and then hooking into the plot-finalising function and calling `dev.off()` there.

But what are these functions? Through debugging I’ve tentatively identified `dev.hold` and `dev.flush` – but is this actually true universally? Can I hook into those functions? I cannot override them with `R.utils`’ `reassignInNamespace` because they are locked, and just putting same-name functions into the global namespace doesn’t work (they’re ignored by `plot`).

---

So, **why** would I want to do something so horrible?

Because I’m working on a remote server and despite my best attempts, and long debugging sessions with our systems support, I cannot get X11 forwarding to work reliably. Not being able to preview a plot is making my workflow horribly inefficient. I’ve given up on trying to get X11 to work so now I’m creating PDFs in my `public_html` folder and just refresh the browser.

This works quite well – except that it‘s really annoying and quite time-consuming to always have to surround your plotting function calls with `pdf(…) … dev.off()`, especially in interactive sessions where you want to quickly create a plot while in a meeting with collaborators. In fact, it’s really annoying and they (understandably) haven’t got the patience for that.

For now I’m helping myself with the following function definition:

```
preview <- function (.expr, ...) {
    on.exit(dev.off())
    pdf(PREVIEW_FILE_NAME, ...)
    eval(substitute(.expr))
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
preview(plot(1:100, rnorm(100) * 1:100))
```

That works a-ok. But *this workflow is a real bottleneck* in meetings, and I’d like to get rid of the `preview` call to streamline it as much as possible.

Any chance at all?

Comment: I used to have this problem as well, I tried X11 forwarding and it was slow and clunky. I tried dropping all my files to pdf as as well, using your pattern. But then I switched to RStudio Server, and all those problems went away. I could quickly preview my plots locally that were computed on the server. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Does the `preview` function actually cost you measurable time? That is, if you run it locally does it cost.  I would have expected the majority of the time would be in writing and reading a remote file. I'd also expect that putting hooks inside `plot` won't be any faster than your `preview` function.   BTW, I don't suppose you have the option to use some other windowserver besides X11, or just to run a remote desktop app? (or see @nograpes nice suggestion)

Comment: @Carl The overhead comes from the added typing, not execution time. And yes, it’s an impact.

Comment: Ok, I gotta be misreading something.  Typing `preview(plot(x[1:35],y[31:65],t='l',col=rainbow(40),xlab="wtf", ylab='fubar',main='this is a lot of typing')` takes measurably longer than typing just the `plot` string?        Something is not right, not the least of which is: if you've got collaborators, then you're doing development work, not a presentation, right? So they should hardly be impatient on the order of a few seconds to see a new algorithm being written and plotted.   So what's really going on?

Comment: Why not `Plot <- function(...) {on.exit(dev.off()); pdf(file="foo.pdf"); plot(...)}`?

Comment: I wonder if some kind of in-browser javascript plotting thing could be useful here? http://rcharts.io/ seems promising

Comment: @Carl Bad formulation. Two reasons. First, as mentioned, bottleneck. It’s not that typing `preview()` takes a lot of time but if you’re in a meeting, and you want to try out plotting data in a new way, typing into the console *stalls conversation*. It’s awkward and annoying. And so you type fast. And make mistakes. And it takes longer. And it gets more annoying. This isn’t limited to me, by the way, I’ve seen this in others as well. Upshot: the innocuous little `preview()` is harmful.

Comment: @Carl Part two, and I actually forgot this in the question: it gets worse. When working alone, I actually use a Vim plugin similar to ESS which pastes code from the script into R. Obviously that absolutely doesn’t work with my `preview` approach since obviously *inside the script* I’m not using `preview`, I’m (explicitly, via `pdf(…)…dev.off()`) plotting to some other output file. So I’d really need to be able to *just* paste the plotting function, and have that work.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Because that *only* works with `plot`, and not any of the myriads of other plotting functions, right?

Comment: If typing stalls conversation, so will any other method of creating a plot.  Maybe you need to move to a TclTK gui with sliders for scaling, buttons for lines and points, dropdown menus for data sources.   I respectfully remain unconvinced that your problem is what you think it is, and that reorganizing the meeting protocols would prove more fruitful.

Comment: @Carl That’s a pity (how does “not typing anything” not sound faster?). So let’s just ignore that and focus on the other use-case, pasting commands from an external editor.

Comment: Can the Vim plugin be easily tinkered with? If so, you might want to customize its paste-to-R command so that it appends each missive with a call to something like `closeall()` where `closall <- function() dummy<-capture.output(replicate(length(dev.list()), dev.off()))`. (This presumes that you've also taken Greg Snow's suggestion to set `options(device="pdf")`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `options(device=FUN)` then the graphics device function `FUN` becomes the new default graphics device that will be opened when a plot is created and device is not already opened.

So, one option would be to write a function that calls `pdf` or `png` or other graphics device with the filename and options that you want (probably `onefile=FALSE` in `pdf`), then set this function as the default in the options.  You may need to use one of `dev.off`, `plot.new`, or `frame` to finalize the current plot (R does not finalize until you close the device or go to a new plot in case you want to add anything to the current plot).

If you will never add to a plot then you could use `addTaskCallback` to call `dev.off` automatically for you.  There may be other hooks that you could use to finalize as well.

Comment: And specifically, do `options(device="pdf")`.  As Greg says, you'll have to do `dev.off()` (or some shorter alias of it) to finalize the plot, but that seems better than expecting R to know when you've finished adding layers to a plot (with `points()`, `lines()`, `legend()`, etc.)