# R redirect all plots including any intermediate state to a file synchronously

Tags: r, plot

How can I redirect all plots including any intermediate state to a file synchronously?

- I want to automatically redirect plots to a file without using expressions like `png(); xxx; dev.off()`. Imagine a in function where users can provide random plotting scripts and I don't know which line of code they start to plot and which line end and how many plots. As long as they make a plot, I want to capture it. One option is to use `options(device="png")`, found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618463/redirect-all-plot-output-to-specific-file).
- `options(device="png")` method will create an empty file named like *Rplot001.png* and when `dev.off` or another top-level plotting function is called, write to the file. So no intermediate state is saved.
- What I want is more like the plots panel in Rstudio: when I make some low-level changes, the image file is updated immediately.

A simple example, I want to plot a point and add a title.

```r
options(device="png")
plot(1)
```

At this point, the plot should be captured by a file automatically, let's name it *Rplot001.png*.

```r
title("abc")
```

Then, the *Rplot001.png* is updated which contains the title.

The problem is when I do this, *Rplot001.png* is not written unless I manually call `dev.off` or open another plot.